# NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationHelperTest::Fill_IN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error message when I add the last test in this code from Ruby on Rails Tutorial, from listing 6.11 and 6.12 and then run the bundle exec rake test Listing 6.13 I am running Linux Xubuntu

> 1) Error:
>       ApplicationHelperTest#test_full_title_helper:
>       NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationHelperTest::FILL_IN
>           test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:5:in `block in '

When I remove the email validation the test passes.

***test/models/user_test.rb***

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = ""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end  
end
```

***app/models/user.rb***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

I think it must have something to do with the Application Helper. this is the code in the helper:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  test "full title helper" do
    assert_equal full_title,         FILL_IN
    assert_equal full_title("Help"), FILL_IN
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the test is trying to look for a constant called `FILL_IN`, which doesn't exist.  The tutorial is asking you to replace `FILL_IN` with proper values.

Comment: This code only gives me one error. I think I need to define a method but am not sure what method.

require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  test "full title helper" do
    assert_equal full_title(name: "Example User")
    assert_equal full_title(email: "user@example.com")        
    end
end

Comment: This is the error, and how come I cant format in these comments.

Comment: 1) Error:
ApplicationHelperTest#test_full_title_helper:
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for {:name=>"Example User"}:Hash
    app/helpers/application_helper.rb:9:in `full_title'
    test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:ApplicationHelperTest>'

10 runs, 18 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

Comment: Since you now have a different issue, I would post a separate question.  Please mark my answer here as accepted, if I've answered you're original question.
Comment formatting is more limited, but you can do code formatting by surrounding a line of code in backticks (`)